# file_get_contents return false in PHP

Tags: php

I am using following code

```
function thumbnailoutput($directory,$count) {
if($directory=='javascript'){
$directory_from_file = file_get_contents('http://example.com/lessons/'.$directory.'/'.$directory.'files.dat');
$urlfileurl = 'http://example.com/lessons/'.$directory.'/urlfiles.dat';
$url_from_file = file_get_contents($urlfileurl);
```

When I use `var_dump($url_from_file);` I get false. I can access

```
http://example.com/lessons/'.$directory.'/urlfiles.dat
```

directly by entering url in browser.

I am calling the function

```
thumbnailoutput('javascript',1);
```

**Why was it downvoted?**

Comment: Is the value of `$directory` `'url'`? It's not clear how the url you're entering into your browser is related to the url generated in your code.

Comment: value of `$directory` is `javascript`

Comment: In that case, the url you're generating is `'http://example.com/lessons/javascript/javascriptfiles.dat'`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I am talking about the value of `$urlfileurl`

Comment: I haven't downvoted your question (yet), but your examples are unclear and you've included unnecessary code - what's the point of including `$directory_from_file` in your example? It's not relevant. Also, what's the point of the `$count` parameter? It's not even used. Also, since `$directory` is always equal to `'javascript'`, there's no need to include the `if` statement at all. As far as I can see, all the code in your question could be condensed down to `$url_from_file = file_get_contents('http://example.com/lessons/javascript/urlfiles.dat');var_dump($url_from_file);`.

Answer (score 0):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns boolean false on error, otherwise the contents, which can be empty and evaluate to false as well.

Are you sure the file has contents?

Comment: Yes it has data. It contains this url `http://www.example.com/lessons/javascript/imageslider.php`

Comment: Try to add `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`before the line. Does it output something?

Comment: It did not output anything.